# Error al descargar zip

Tags: php

Hola les escribo solicitando ayuda por un error que me envía el servidor al tratar de descargar un archivo zip. Me indica 500 (Internal Server Error).

Me tiene vuelto loco el problema ya que no he podido encontrar la solución.

Dejo el codigo en el cual realizo la descarga. Lo otro mi pagina la tengo en un servidor local con SO ubuntu server 16.04.

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");

    if(isset($_GET['cuenta'])){
            $cuenta=$_GET['cuenta'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['fecha_inicio'])){
            $fecha_inicio=$_GET['fecha_inicio'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['fecha_termino'])){
            $fecha_termino=$_GET['fecha_termino'];
    }
    $año=date("Y",strtotime($fecha_termino));
    $mess=date("m",strtotime($fecha_termino));
    if ($mess==1){$fecha='Enero '.$año;}
    if ($mess==2){$fecha='Febrero '.$año;}
    if ($mess==3){$fecha='Marzo '.$año;}
    if ($mess==4){$fecha='Abril '.$año;}
    if ($mess==5){$fecha='Mayo '.$año;}
    if ($mess==6){$fecha='Junio '.$año;}
    if ($mess==7){$fecha='Julio '.$año;}
    if ($mess==8){$fecha='Agosto '.$año;}
    if ($mess==9){$fecha='Septiembre '.$año;}
    if ($mess==10){$fecha='Octubre '.$año;}
    if ($mess==11){$fecha='Noviembre '.$año;}
    if ($mess==12){$fecha='Diciembre '.$año;}
    $zipname='Prefacturado '.$cuenta.' '.$fecha.'.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zipname,ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT numero FROM reportes where nombre_empresa='$cuenta' and fecha_inicio between '$fecha_inicio' and '$fecha_termino' order by fecha_inicio ASC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
            $sql1=mysqli_query($conexion,"select reporte FROM documentos WHERE id_reporte='$row[0]'");
            $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
            if($row1[0]!='SI'){
                    $ruta=$row1[0];
                    $reporte=substr($ruta,36);
                    $zip->add($row1[0],$reporte);
            }


    }
    $zip->close();
    header("Content-Type: application/zip,application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$zipname);
    readfile($zipname);
    unlink($zipname);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la soclucion y mi error estaba en la linea

```
$zip->add($row1[0],$reporte);
```

era

```
$zip->addFile($row1[0],$reporte);
```

y ahora funciona de maravillas.